# Could not connect the Intelligence Server - Microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

When attempting to start the MicroStrategy Intelligence Server **10.6** service via the MicroStrategy Service Manager or Windows Services, the following error occurs:

[image]

[image]

I'm on windows 10

**Edit #1: Additional infos:**

This is the Windows Event Viewer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's 10.6 and not 9.x
Did you just upgrade ?

Comment: Yes it's mstr 10.6, I install it directly, not upgraded

Comment: Can you do a 'repair' installation and see if it solves ?

Comment: I edited the post, please check the windows Event Viewer if you get an idea.

Comment: Can you check your dsserror log and see if there's something there ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link on MicroStrategy knowledge base portal.

https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Server/TN34508-quot-Failed-to-start-service-Unexpected-error-occurred/ta-p/185147